# Are circular references acceptable in database?

Tags: database, oracle, circular-dependency

When are circular references acceptable in database?

Theoretical and practical, any help is appreciated.

Comment: not even close to being a question! PLease supply more detail...

Comment: Circular references, no. Spherical references are okay. You're encouraged to look into that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Don't listen to people claiming "circular ref is the devil" of course they can be tricky to deal with when used wrong... but there are many valid use cases, where they are the best option - so use them!!!

Comment: Check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006917/are-circular-references-acceptable-in-database

Comment: [**Deferrable SQL Constraints**: Cyclic Foreign Keys](https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html) is a great in-depth look at circular references with examples.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Records which point to other records are useful in a database.  Sometimes these records form a cycle.  This might still be useful.  The only real annoyance in practice is avoiding violating the constraints.

For example, if you have a user and transaction table, the user might have a pointer to his last transaction.  You need to insert the transaction first, then update the `last_transaction_id` to the correct value.  While both these records exist you can't erase them, because the `user.last_transaction_id` points to `transaction.id` and `transaction.user_id` points to `user.id`.  This implies that a user with no transactions has a null `last_transaction_id`.  It also means that you have to null that field before you can delete the transaction.

Managing these foreign key constraints is a pain but it certainly is possible.  There may be problems that arise if you add constraints to the database later which introduce new circular dependencies.  You have to be careful in this situation.  However, as long as one of the records in the cycle has a nullable foreign-key field, the cycle can be broken and the records can be deleted.  Updates are not usually a problem as long as you insert the records in the right order.

Answer (score 46):

Consider cities and states.  Each city exists within a state.  Each state has a capital city.

```sql
CREATE TABLE city (
  city  VARCHAR(32),
  state VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (city),
  FOREIGN KEY (state) REFERENCES state (state)
);

CREATE TABLE state (
  state VARCHAR(32),
  capital_city VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (state),
  FOREIGN KEY (capital_city) REFERENCES city (city)
);
```

First problem - You cannot create these tables as shown, because a foreign key can't reference a column in a table that doesn't (yet) exist. The solution is to create them without the foreign keys, and then add the foreign keys afterwards.

Second problem - you cannot insert rows into either table, as each insert will require a pre-existing row in the other table.  The solution is to set one of 
the foreign key columns to be NULL, and insert that data in two phases.  e.g.

```sql
--Create state record
INSERT INTO state (state, capital_city) VALUES ('Florida', NULL);

--Create various city records
INSERT INTO city (city, state) VALUES ('Miami', 'Florida');
INSERT INTO city (city, state) VALUES ('Tallahassee', 'Florida');
INSERT INTO city (city, state) VALUES ('Orlando', 'Florida');

--Set one of the cities as the capital
UPDATE state SET capital_city = 'Tallahassee' WHERE state = 'Florida';
```

Comment: Thanks. Good example. SQL server gives error for this circular ref - oreign key 'FK__city__state__007EABC' references invalid table 'state'. Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: Other possibilities to insert rows without allowing NULL-Values: 1. INSERT ALL, 2. Deferrable Constraints. Also when deleting: 3. DELESE CASCADE

Comment: @Falco Can you please point to a (working) example of using INSERT ALL with circular FK?

Comment: Why is it not possible to do it with two inserts in one transaction? My assumption was that constraints should only be checked at the end of a transaction, but apparently it is not the case.

Comment: Some databases (e.g. postgresql) allow you to defer constraint checking until the end of the transaction, using a command such as SET CONSTRAINTS foo, bar DEFERRED

Comment: PostgreSQL and Oracle support `DEFERRABLE` constraints. Use the option `INITIALLY DEFERRED` to check such constraints at the end of transactions (as opposed to the end of each statement). Place conflicting or circular statements within a transaction.

Comment: How do you add the foreign keys after creation?

Comment: You can add  foreign key constraint to an existing table using a statement such as `ALTER TABLE child ADD FOREIGN KEY my_fk (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(ID);`

Answer (score 5):

It is technically possible to do, but it can cause all sorts of problems when deleting records as it generates chicken-and-egg problems.  These problems often take drastic action like manually dropping the FK's and deleting the offending items to resolve.

If you have a relationship like:

```
create table foo_master (
       foo_master_id int not null primary key
      ,current_foo_id int
)


create table foo_detail (
       foo_detail_id int not null primary key
       foo_master_id int not null
)

alter table foo_master
  add constraint fk_foo_current_detail
      foreign key (current_foo_id)
      references foo_detail

alter table foo_detail
  add constraint fk_foo_master
      foreign key (foo_master_id)
      references foo_master
```

Then deleting a record can cause such a chicken-and-agg problem due to the circular dependencies.

A better schema for this looks like:

```
create table foo_master (
       foo_master_id int not null primary key
)


create table foo_detail (
       foo_detail_id int not null primary key
       foo_master_id int not null
       is_current char (1)
)

alter table foo_detail
  add constraint fk_foo_master
      foreign key (foo_master_id)
      references foo_master
```

This means that the relationship is non-cyclic and the 'current' foo_detail record can still be identified.

Answer (score 5):

One of the latest additions to the Oracle hierarchical query syntax - the `NOCYCLE` keyword - was made for expressly this purpose - to deal with circular references in the data. I don't see anything wrong with it, and have had to deal with this kind of model before. It's not too difficult, especially in Oracle which supports deferrable constraints.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen circular references done for performance reasons.  It looks ugly though, and the performance might be negligible.

Example: some bulletin boards (I think phpBB does this) have a lastpostid in the category table that is a shortcut to the last post in the thread.

This creates a circle, where the last post has a FK to the category table and the category table has a FK back to the last post.

Like I said, I don't really like it, but I've seen it done.

Answer (score 0):

Circular references should be avoided like the plague. It is possible to set up two way relationships, or even relationships to yourself (if you were a table that is), but a circular dependency is just asking for trouble.

Comment: what do you mean by a two-way relationship? record A points to B and C? As opposed to A points to B and B points to A? the second one is definitely circular.

Answer (score 0):

rarely i run across a 1:1 relationship that is necessary and imposes a circular relationship

note that the foreign-key fields in such a relationship must be nullable, otherwise you can never delete rows from the tables

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isn't a problem if you are using a write only database. If you plan on using the RUD part of CRUD, you'll likely run into (usually avoidable) complex issues in dealing with them.