# The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to update my database with "update-database" command in package manager console, But I have this kind of error:

```
The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one 
relationship between 'Country.CapitalCity' and 'CapitalCity.Country'. To 
identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign 
key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same 
relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.
```

My Model classes look like this:

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }

    public int CapitalCityID { get; set; }
    public CapitalCity CapitalCity { get; set; }
}

public class CapitalCity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

After searching info about this problem, I added the following code in my DbContextModelSnapshot, but I still have problem.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasOne(a => a.CapitalCity)
            .WithOne(a => a.Country)
            .HasForeignKey<CapitalCity>(c => c.CountryID);
```

What mistake do I have?

Comment: Don't modify `DbContextModelSnapshot`, put that code inside `OnModelCreating` of your db context derived class, then generate migration.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have to put the below code in your DBContext class, not in SnapShot class. Don’t modify the Snapshot class, it’s auto generated class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasOne(a => a.CapitalCity)
            .WithOne(a => a.Country)
            .HasForeignKey<CapitalCity>(c => c.CountryID);
```

Comment: As you said, I put this code in OnModelCreating method in my DbContext but no I am getting this error in console : Project 'Default' is not found.

Comment: You need to select your host project as startup project ..and make sure you have selected the project which has dbcontext class as default project in package manager console.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point it out if you don't really need a one-to-one relationship you can solve it like this and the migration will work out of the box. Valid if a `CapitalCity` can share the same name with different Countries in this example. You would of course need to factor the possibility that one country changes its capital city name but the other country does not.

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }

    public int CapitalCityID { get; set; }
    public CapitalCity CapitalCity { get; set; }
}

public class CapitalCity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this case the better solution would probably be like this though:

```
public class Country
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }

    public List<CapitalCity> CapitalCities { get; set; } = new List<CapitalCity>();
}

public class CapitalCity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I think it is better because a lot of countries have or had multiple capital cities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_with_multiple_capitals

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify the foreign key in the DBContext class. You can also just add the
`public int CountryId { get; set; }`
to your CapitalCity class

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the primary key may not be equal. Therefore, you should check that the primary key of all relations is the same.
If you can't check, you can do the following:

```
builder.Entity<Country>()
    .HasOne(a => a.CapitalCity)
    .WithOne(a => a.Country)
    .HasForeignKey<Country>(c => c.CapitalCityID);
```

enter `HasForeignKey<Country>` for all `WithOne`s to get this warning

`The relationship from 'User.AppUser' to 'AppUser.User' with foreign key properties {'CapitalCityID' : int} cannot target the primary key {'ID' : long} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.`

Then you can identify and fix the interference

Comment: That doesn't answer the question and it is a needlessly complex solution to something that can readily be checked in the code just by looking at property types.

Answer (score -1):

```
The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
```

EF Core does not know who the parent or the child is since both of the models have the ID of each other. That is a circular dependency and EF Core does not like that.
see: [Are circular references acceptable in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006917/are-circular-references-acceptable-in-database)

Comment: Given that there is a well established answer and others on this question, you need to make sure that this is helpful and contributes to the conversation. Your assessment of the situation is not 100% correct, while EF thinks this is a circular reference this particular data scenario in the database is actually a composite key, which is both valid and common and can be supported in EF but really should be avoided to simplify logic. A solution that describes that would be helpful, but this generic response doesn't directly apply to the original post.

Comment: The OP asked what mistakes he had, I wanted to point out that having foreign keys on both classes, causes EF Core to confuse the parent/child. I presumed that counts as a solution.
I also presumed that maybe OP was trying to create a circular dependency, so I wanted to point out why EF core will not accept that.

Comment: But you didn't offer a solution just a generic rewording of the error message. 6 years ago OP accepted a solution and moved on, so we aren't helping OP anymore. But let's look closer, was OP trying to create a circular dp or is that an accidental byproduct of misunderstanding how relationships work?

Comment: "was OP trying to create a circular dp or is that an accidental byproduct of misunderstanding how relationships work?"
Either one or both, so I pasted the error, and I explained the relevant error; having both foreign keys of both models on each other will confuse EF Core, and I also put a link that gave an answer that is might be what he was trying to do in the DB.
Not exactly sure if he was creating a composite key, The answer he accepted did not implement a composite key.

Comment: I understand its 6 years ago. I don't mean to be rude, I just want to say that this is stack overflow, I'm not answering just to solve OP's problem, I'm answering for people who might find this relevant in the future; people like me who made the same mistake and found this on the top search result.
The top answer did not discover or solve OP's mistake, the mistake is still there but forcibly bypassed.

Comment: That's the problem though, the relationship is supported if you want it, it's just configured wrong. So you further explained the error, but didn't offer a solution other than "don't do that" so this is really a non-answer and should be a comment in its current state. You could make it into a real answer with more information. If your answer is just linking to an existing one then maybe you should flag as a duplicate. In my opinion its an incomplete question because OP doesn't explain the change or provide any reasoning.