# DbSets with Subtypes: The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808912/the-child-dependent-side-could-not-be-determined-for-the-one-to-one-relationship/51809814), I'm trying to get my EF object model squared away, and UNLIKE the linked question, I am in fact setting up the modelBuilder calls inside the actual DbContext, not a Snapshot. It looks something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>()
        .HasOne(a => a.MyProfile)
        .WithOne(a => a.MyUser)
        .HasForeignKey<MyProfile>(c => c.Id)
        .HasPrincipalKey<MyUser>(x => x.UserIntId);
```

One difference here is that both `MyUser` and `MyProfile` inherit from other types, `UserEntity` and `ProfileEntity`, which in turn have associated properties, i.e. `UserEntity` has `UserEntity.Profile` of type `ProfileEntity` and `ProfileEntity` has `ProfileEntity.User` of type `UserEntity`.

So, the exception I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'UserEntity.Profile' and 'ProfileEntity.User'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

I'm not sure how to resolve this exception in this case without totally removing the inheritance (which I would like to avoid in order to save time having to do a refactor of base libraries).

Comment: Share us the full code for `MyUser`,`MyProfile`,`UserEntity` and `ProfileEntity`

Comment: The issue I ran into here is that there were some inheritance issues and some other objects in the DI container also configuring the same relations. I cleaned those up and this resolved.

Comment: You could append your solution as answer.